# Make arr of objects with the same key javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arr

```
let arr = [ 
    {tags: {x: 2, y: 12}}, 
    {type: {x: 23, y: 44}}, 
    {order: {x: 5, y: 1200}}, 
]
```

and need (the same key, but value must come from current x)

```
let arr = [ 
  {tags: 2}, 
  {type: 23}, 
  {order: 5} 
]
```

what I try

```
arr.map(({ k, v }) => { [k]: v.x });
```

Please about help!!

Comment: Please try: `const newArr = arr.map(obj => ({ Object.keys(obj)[0]: obj.x }));` It's not the best, but I think it'll work for this case.

Comment: @jsN00b This won't work because `x` is not a property of the object but of the sub-object.

Comment: exactly, I doesnt work because of that

Comment: Noted. Will post an answer. EDIT: And, answer posted. :-) Thank you @CherryDT and karo-s.

Answer (score 1):

This should be one possible way to obtain the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
let arr = [ 
    {tags: {x: 2, y: 12}}, 
    {type: {x: 23, y: 44}}, 
    {order: {x: 5, y: 1200}}, 
];

const res = arr.flatMap(
  obj => Object.entries(obj).map(
    ([k, {x}]) => ({ [k]: x })
  )
);

console.log(res);
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate over the array using `.flatMap()` (to avoid nested-array in the result)
- Take each object (`obj`) and iterate over key-value pairs using `Object.entries()`
- Now, de-structure the `[key, value]` iterator to directly access prop `x`
- Transform it to an object with `x` as the value

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [ 
    {tags: {x: 2, y: 12}}, 
    {type: {x: 23, y: 44}}, 
    {order: {x: 5, y: 1200}}, 
]

arr.map((item) => {
    const newItem = {}
    newItem[ Object.keys(item)[0]] = item[Object.keys(item)[0]].x
    return newItem
})
```

This is my solution. It's worked but I don't think it is good answer!

Comment: The function body can be simplified to `({ [Object.keys(item)[0]]: item[Object.keys(item)[0]].x })`.

Comment: It is a good answer. Why you think it isn't? Just as you used Object.keys(), we can even do: `newItem[ Object.keys(item)[0] ] = Object.values(item)[0].x;`. Or, we can de-structure and do: `const [ k, { x } ] = Object.entries(item)[0];` and then say: `newItem[k] = x;`. So many different ways to get the same result. :-)

Comment: thanks both of you. I'm not familiar with Object.entries so that's why I'm doing like that. I think it's a simple/easy-to-understand way to solve this. I don't think my answer is not good now. Now I know why I feel weird, maybe bc of how the array structured. none of api should return smth like that.

Answer (score 0):

You're moving in the right direction. You just need `Object.entries` to help you get `k` and `v` as an array `[k, v]`.

```js
let arr = [ {tags: {x: 2, y: 12}}, {type: {x: 23, y: 44}}, {order: {x: 5, y: 1200}} ];

const output = arr.flatMap(
  o => Object.entries(o).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]:v.x}))
);
console.log( output );
```

Alternatively, since `v` has the same properties in all the elements, you can use destructuring as in the demo below:

```js
let arr = [ {tags: {x: 2, y: 12}}, {type: {x: 23, y: 44}}, {order: {x: 5, y: 1200}} ];

const output = arr.flatMap(
  o => Object.entries(o).map(([k,{x,y}]) => ({[k]:x}))
);
console.log( output );
```